# Angular / Ionic - Handle JSON "error" property

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using TypeScript, Angular 5.0. My backend response is summarized in this interface:

```
export interface JSONResponse {
  error?: {
    code: number,
    message: string
  };
  data?: {};
}
```

The function in my service to get the data from the server is:

```
httpGet(url: string, httpParams: HttpParams) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.http.get<LoginResponse>(url, {params: httpParams})
      .subscribe(res => {
        resolve(res.data);
      }, err => {
        // handle http get related errors here
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
}
```

And then the component that consume this service to render the template:

```
buttonClicked(event) {
  this.myService.httpGet('myAPIurl', someRequestParams)
    .then((data) => {
      this.myData = data;
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Where would be the place to handle the error checking of the response from my backend?

That is, if property `data` is present, the response is successful and do the proper processing of my data; if property `error` is present, I notify the user with the code/message error.

Comment: What is the issue right now you have?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out where is the place in the code to perform the JSON parsing, and check whether the data or error field exists or not, and eventually inform in the UI the processed data or the error

Comment: Why can't you do it here `(err) => {
      console.log(err);` in the `buttonClicked()` event?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do it in a more generic way you can use [**IonicErrorHandler**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/IonicErrorHandler/).

> The IonicErrorHandler intercepts the default Console error handling
>   and displays runtime errors as an overlay when using Ionic's Dev Build
>   Server.

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';

@NgModule({
  providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }]
})
class AppModule {}
```

If you want to customise it you can do that too.

```
class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  handleError(err: any): void {
    // do something with the error
  }
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler }]
})
class AppModule {}
```